Mixed Model: Translation from mathematical notation to R's lmer() - package: lmerTest
The following data should be generated and fitted to a mixed model (for further simulation studies):

$y$: outcome of clinical study (effect of medication)
indiv individuals = 20
repl replicate measurements per individual taken on consecutive days after the treatment = 10
explanatory variables:
- $x_1$ ... the treatment (2 treatments) - half of the individuals receive treatment/placebo
- $x_2$ ... the time of measurement (in days, 1...10 (continuous predictor))
- $x_3$ ... indicator coding the individual

Underlying model: $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \gamma_1(x_3) + \gamma_2(x_3)*x_2 + \epsilon$
Furthermore $\beta_0 = 1$, $\beta_1 = 1$, $\beta_2 = 0.5$, $\gamma_1(x_3) \sim N(0,4)$ i.i.d., $\gamma_2(x_3) \sim N(0,1)$ i.i.d., $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$ i.i.d.
library(lmerTest)

sim.data <- function(indiv,repl,param.beta,param.gamma.1,param.gamma.2,param.eps) {
  
  indiv <- indiv          # number of individuals / people
  repl <- repl            # number of replications (= number of measurements) per individual
  
  b.0 <- param.beta[1]    # betas
  b.1 <-  param.beta[2]
  b.2 <-  param.beta[3]
  
  x.1 <- rep(0:1,each=indiv/2*repl)   # Treatment: no,yes
  x.2 <- rep(1:10,indiv)              # day of treatment per individual
  x.3 <- rep(1:indiv,each=repl)       # indicator coding the individual
  
  gamma.1 <- rnorm(indiv,mean=param.gamma.1[1],sd=param.gamma.1[2])
  gamma.2 <- rnorm(indiv,mean=param.gamma.2[1],sd=param.gamma.2[2])
  
  g1 <- gamma.1[x.3]   # intercept random effects
  g2 <- gamma.2[x.3]   # slope random effects
  
  e <- rnorm(length(x.1))
  
  y <- b.0 + b.1*x.1 + b.2*x.2 + g1 + g2*x.2 + e
  
  data.sim <- data.frame(x.1 = x.1,
                         x.2 = x.2,
                         x.3 = x.3,
                         y = y)
  
  return(data.sim)
  
}

set.seed(1234)
data <- sim.data(20,10,c(1,1,0.5),c(0,4),c(0,1),c(0,1))

mod <- lmer(y ~ x.1 + x.2 + (1 + x.2|x.3), REML = FALSE, data = data)
mod


Question:
The output shows, that the fixed effects are not estimated close to the true values (betas). Can somebody explain please, what I misinterpreted and help with the code? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

This is a really great start. You were almost there! See below for some suggested edits. The one thing you were missing in the initial code was that you did not have the param.eps baked into the line that creates e in the function. I added that. Also, with these simulations, you often have to up the sample size, sometimes considerably, to fully recover the parameters.
sim.data <- function(indiv,repl,param.beta,param.gamma.1,param.gamma.2,param.eps) {
  
  indiv <- round(indiv)          # number of individuals / people
  repl <- repl            # number of replications (= number of measurements) per individual
  
  b.0 <- param.beta[1]    # betas - fixed effects
  b.1 <-  param.beta[2]
  b.2 <-  param.beta[3]
  
  x.1 <-  rep(rep(0:1, each = repl), length.out = indiv * repl)   # Treatment: no,yes; what if uneven # of groups
  x.2 <- rep(1:10,length.out = indiv * repl)              # day of treatment per individual
  id <- rep(1:indiv,each = repl)       # indicator coding the individual
  
  gamma.1 <- rnorm(indiv,mean=param.gamma.1[1],sd=param.gamma.1[2])
  gamma.2 <- rnorm(indiv,mean=param.gamma.2[1],sd=param.gamma.2[2])
  
  g1 <- gamma.1[id]   # intercept random effects
  g2 <- gamma.2[id]   # slope random effects
  
  e <- rnorm(length(x.1), mean=param.eps[1],sd=param.eps[2])
  
  y <- b.0 + b.1*x.1 + b.2*x.2 + g1 + g2*x.2 + e
  
  data.sim <- data.frame(x.1 = x.1,
                         x.2 = x.2,
                         id = id,
                         y = y)
  
  return(data.sim)
  
}

Then initialize the simulation:
set.seed(1234)
data <- sim.data(
  indiv = 200, 
  repl = 10, 
  param.beta = c(1, 2, 0.5), 
  param.gamma.1 = c(0, 4), 
  param.gamma.2 = c(0, 1), 
  param.eps = c(0, 1)
)

The last thing that you were slightly off on was your lmer() statement. Since you did not simulate a correlation between the random slope and intercept, you should omit that from the code, which is done with the || in the random part of the model specification. I don't think it hurts if you estimate the correlation, but we know that, by design, this correlation is 0.
mod <- lme4::lmer(y ~ x.1 + x.2 + (1 + x.2||id), REML = FALSE, data = data)
summary(mod)

Parameter recovery is good once you bump up the number of individuals to 200. This is likely due to the relatively small effects you are plugging in here.

Nice answer. It can be very useful to look at the summary of results from many replicates of this kind of simulation/fitting combination; that gives you much more information about whether the problem is bias (often problematic/means you made a mistake) or variance (often an unavoidable issue with small simulated sample sizes).

Thank you so much for all your help!

My pleasure, @m09s19! You deserve the credit for figuring out the hardest parts of this.
